# Is it appropriate to move a question to Maths Overflow if it is the subject of current research?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

My question [Determine Max queue size with a time nonhomogeneous customer rate.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583860/determine-max-queue-size-with-a-time-nonhomogeneous-customer-rate) doesn't seem to be getting much responses and my own searching of the literature seems to indicate that examination of questions like this was happening as recently as 1985.  I suspect that it may be a topic of ongoing research or one that hasn't been studied in depth.

Is it appropriate to rewrite the question to be in keeping with math overflow and ask it there?

Comment: There is a vast amount of literature on queuing theory, and I suspect the problem you posed has been treated.  That said, I see no reason to rush to posting at MathOverflow while the bonus is still active here.  Your idea, that the queue can be approximately modeled by piecewise constant arrival rates, is valid and worth pursuing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is considered as admissible to ask a question on both sites if all of the following conditions are met:

- A reasonable amount of time has passed between the two postings (a week).
- References in both directions are provided (it'd also be nice if once you get an answer on one site you "transfer" the knowledge to the other as well).

Of course the questions needs to be admissible for each site individually. Whether or not this questions is suitable for MO, you'll have to decide for yourself or inquire there.